# Quickly straighten and crop a large number of photos

Tags: windows, gratis, image-processing, photography

I have taken several hundred photographs at an event. I would like to do some simple, quick editing of these, before sharing them. Specifically, rotating the photo to straighten it, and cropping it as required.

This should be a quick process. ie open a photo, rotate, crop, then save it, and load the next photo in the folder.

Optionally, it could resize all of the photos to a specific size. Though this can be done in bulk afterwards if necessary.

The software should run on Windows 7, and preferably free of charge. Bonus if it is also free/open source.